# pickadate plugin exception when JQuery not loaded in the same file

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gruntjs

I have a list of js files which are minified and bundled into a couple of files by grunt (but that shouldn't matter, I suppose):

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/affix.js"></script>
...
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/popover.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js scripts/modules.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
...
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="Shared/Scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="Shared/Scripts/picker.js"></script>
<script src="Shared/Scripts/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="Shared/Scripts/picker.time.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Once grunt runs, the result looks like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/1d5f71.plugins.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/42cce7.modules.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/410a58.scripts.js"></script>
```

Now the very first time picker.js (minified and bundled into 410a58.scripts.js file) goes "this.Picker", it complains that "cannot set property 'Picker' of undefined". If I copy jquery.min.js to the top of 410a58.scripts.js, then the issue goes away.

I thought it might be due to jquery not being loaded from cdn, but that's not the case. There are various libraries in plugins.js etc. which need jquery and will throw an exception if that file is not loaded from cdn.

The exact line which is causing the error is this.Picker = factory( jQuery ) which is transformed into this.Picker=a(jQuery) after minification.

For obvious reasons, I am not able paste the whole thing. Any ideas what I should be looking for?

Comment: did you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: As far as I remember, I wasn't able to find a real solution for this. I ended up doing the good old remove all packages and npm install and update and a few tinkerings like this. Sorry!